# Camera Calculation

Tags: sprites, andengine, cocos2d-x, viewport

For my game I don't able to decide what camera resolution I have to use ?

Normally I use 1024x600 landscape resolution of camera for my game and create single graphics for my game.

But I found that my chosen resolution was not perfect enough, in some device it shows black bar that does not render by the game engine.

So what I have to do for camera that support all type of android device that I am not able to decide.
If I have to create multiple graphics that also suggest me about that option also.
What resolution I have to choose so that It runs on all type of android devices and from graphics designer I have to create which resolution graphics?

Thanks guys for your help because I got a lot from you.

EDIT : I like to mention that my current development platform is AndEngine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask for the device's resolution, and then, set the viewport to fit it.
I assume that you are using Cocos2d X, they call it Multi Resolution, hope [this helps](http://ucollide.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/cocos2d-x-2-0-2-multi-resolution-support/).

---

**Edit:**
[This post](http://www.jesusbosch.com/2012/06/cross-platform-and-cross-device-screen.html) from Jesús bosch may give extra information about the topic.

Comment: I edited my question, if you have information then please help me and also information provided by your supplied link become useful to me. I up voted your answer but that was not what I want to get so I didn't mark as correct. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Sorry, for the tag I thought it was cocos2d-x, I do not know about AndEngine, only found this http://andengine.wikidot.com/detect-screen-resolution
and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537771/how-to-run-my-game-for-different-screen-resolution-using-andengine